# Пост(блок)/пост(-блок)

Tags: орфография

Как правильно в скобках оставлять часть слова, давая, это делая, знать, что эта часть слова – факультативна? Надо ли всегда использовать дефис или его, только когда вторая часть слова через дефис была бы написана, надо писать?

Например, есть слово *Том-кот*. Если я хочу показать, что *-кот* необязательно писать, то мне, как я понимаю, надо обязательно включить дефис, – не так ли? – то есть будет *Том(-кот)*. Ещё: *перекати-поле – перекати(-поле)*.

А если у нас, как пример, слово *постблок*, то, если я то же хочу сделать, мне надо писать *пост(блок)* или – добавляя дефис таки всё равно, несмотря на то что слово само по себе слитно пишется, – *пост(-блок)*?

Comment: Кто-то разгадал смысл этого слова (см. комментарии)?

Answer (score 0):

**Том-кот  или Том (кот)**

Информация про то, что **Том — это кот** указывается в определенных случаях. Это можно указать в скобках, а можно использовать дефис. Но дефисное написание регулируется **правилами,** а также такая запись должна соответствовать **семантике.**

Родовое слово ***кот*** может обозначать нужную семантику, например: *У одного моего знакомого есть кот Том, а у другого  — собака Том. И я часто  слушаю их рассказы про Тома-кота и Тома-щенка . Или: рассказы про  Тома (кота) и Тома- щенка).*

Слово ***кот*** может использоваться для обозначения **стиля:** художественного (для создания единого образа) или иронического. Например:  *Что-то наш Том-кот сегодня спит целый день. А наш Том-кот  (или кот Том) сегодня не в духе…*

**2. Пост (блок) или пост-блок**

(1) **Постом** считается небольшое **сообщение**, помещенное на стене страницы, зарегистрированной в соц. сети. Тематическую направленность поста (контента) определяет владелец аккаунта. Главный критерий поста — это интересная и доступная людям и поисковым системам информация.

(2) **Пост** – это небольшой информационный **блок**, размещенный в соцсети, на форуме или в личном блоге. Зачастую он содержит, помимо текста, картинки, ссылки, графики, аудио - и видео-материалы.  И тогда можно сделать вывод: пост - отдельное сообщение,  а блок содержит различные материалы

Здесь лучше написать **пост (блок),** так как слово ***пост-блок*** не нормировано словарем или правилами.

**3. ***Перекати-поле*** (словарное слово)**

***ПЕРЕКАТИ-ПОЛЕ***, -я; мн. нет; ср. 1. Степное и пустынное травянистое или полукустарниковое растение, при созревании отрывающееся от корня и перекатываемое ветром. 2. Неодобр. О человеке, склонном к частой смене местожительства, работы.
В этом случае менять написание слова нельзя.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148792/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: *И тогда можно сделать вывод: пост - отдельное сообщение, а блок содержит различные материалы* — нет, нельзя сделать такой вывод, это бред, ни капли логики. Блоком можно назвать прямоугольник из текста (нет отступов, выровнено и т.п.). Сейчас блоком часто называют однородный прямоугольный предмет ("кирпичный блок" и т.п.), в информатике просто прямоугольная область.

Comment: *не нормировано словарем или правилами* — что точно не нормировано, так это замена "ни..., ни" (*не нормировано ни словарём, ни правилами*) на "или".